# Procedimiento no retorna select correctamente

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Buen día!
Estoy tratando de crear un procedimiento en mariadb, uno que al insertar un valor pasado por parámetro regrese un select de una tabla que obtiene el valor de un campo que sea igual al valor que mando (este procedimiento será parte de uno más complejo).

El problema es que, pasando el valor por parámetro no me retorna resultado el select, pero si lo escribo directamente en el procedimiento, si me retorna el select. El procedimiento lo estoy haciendo en phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM t_login_usuarios where user LIKE @usuario
```

En parámetros le pongo como dirección "in", en nombre "usuario", en longitud "60" (que es la misma longitud de mi campo user) y en opciones pongo "juego de carácteres".

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el Concat para agregarle los operadores % al Like

```
SELECT * FROM t_login_usuarios where user LIKE CONCAT('%',@usuario,'%')
```

---

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE logearalsistema(IN usuario varchar(60))
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM t_login_usuarios 
    WHERE USER 
    LIKE CONCAT('%',usuario,'%');
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Ya lo intenté y sigue arrojando nada, retorna el select si le pongo el dato directamente sin usar variables

Comment: Podrías adjuntar el procedimiento a la pregunta?

Comment: DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `LogearAlSistema`(IN `usuario` VARCHAR(60) CHARSET latin1)
    READS SQL DATA
SELECT * FROM t_login_usuarios WHERE user LIKE @usuario$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: Modifique la respuesta, agrega el Begin y el End a tu Procedimiento, debería funcionar, también podrías adjuntar capturas de pantalla del resultado del procedimiento y del select sin variables para ver mejor el resultado

Comment: Ya lo resolví, como al principio defino la variable, ya no es necesario poner un arroba para llamarla.